# How to uninstall partially installed Office 2016

Tags: microsoft-office, uninstall

While I was installing Office 2016, the battery died. When I turned on PC, I tried to complete installation and to uninstall office, but the PC does not allow this. In Control Panel --> Programs and Features there is an entry to uninstall, but it does not work.

Comment: Try a system restore. Otherwise reinstalling office or doing a repair, then uninstalling again may work.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Be specific and detailed!

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to uninstall office. If the normal way doesn't work, there's a removal tool you could use that Microsoft offers (from [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2016-Office-2013-or-Office-365-from-a-PC-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8)) that manually remove all office installation files from your computer. The Office Removal Tool can be downloaded from Microsoft [here](https://aka.ms/diag_officeuninstall) (official Microsoft download) or google Microsoft Office Removal Tool yourself.